# Predictability of what $\lfloor n\log n\rfloor$ "skips"

Tags: functions, logarithms, recreational-mathematics

TL;DR: is there any way to tell what numbers will not be present in the function $\lfloor n\log n\rfloor$ under a given upperbound?

---

I am writing a program that will calculate the sum of the gaps in the function $\lfloor n\log n\rfloor$ under an inputted upperbound. The gaps can be gathered from the chart below. $$\begin{array}{c|cccccccccccc}n & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12\\\hline \lfloor n\log n\rfloor & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 7 & 8 & 10 & 11 & 12\end{array}.$$ The gaps in this example are $6$ and $9$, for they are skipped. Let $h(u)$ be the output of the program in question, $u$ the upperbound. The table above shows $h(12)$, and is $15$.

I am trying to optimize this program. Currently, I brute-force my way through all values concerned.

I wonder now if there is any predictability to the gaps. I have analyzed the pattern for some time, but I have thus far been able to find any, other than that, as $n$ grows, the average gap density increases, probably because $x^x$ grows faster for larger $x$.

Comment: Your table puzzled me until I realized that you are using base-$10$ logarithms, not natural logarithms.

Comment: @RobertIsrael isn't the natural logarithm $\ln$?

Comment: Yes, but $\log$ is also used.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Notational_conventions

Comment: @RobertIsrael huh. That explains a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be effectively calculated. Especially since the size of the gaps significantly increases as n increases. For example, if $n > e^{10}$, the gaps have a size of at least 10.

Your problem can be solved easier. The sum of all numbers between $0$ and $n$ is known to be $\frac{n(n+ 1)}{2}$. From this value, you just need to substract all those numbers in the range from $0$ to $n$ that can be expressed as $\lfloor i \log(i)\rfloor$.

Comment: Yes, this is the approach I am using, but is hopelessly useless for large $n$ (i.e., $n=10^{10}$). I wasn't sure if predictability existed; I guess it doesn't. Thanks!